# PHP MySQL - SELECT SUM return issue

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to perform the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(cash) AS total_cash FROM users
```

The query should give me back a `SUM()` of the total cash which I've paid out to users in the form of a field named `total_cash`.

My HTML/PHP is as follows:

```
<p class="cash_count">
$<? 
    $total_cash = $db->GetNumRows($db->Query("SELECT SUM(cash) AS total_cash FROM users"));
    echo number_format($total_cash);
?>
</p> paid out!
```

I know `GetNumRows` will always show `1` as there's only `1` row, but I don't know what to use instead, can anybody guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using some class to connect to database - you have not specified anything about that class. If $db->Query() returns the actual mysql resource, you can do this:

```
$res=$db->Query("...."); 
$r=mysql_fetch_object($res);
echo $r->total_cash;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's only 1 row, because your query ask for the `SUM`, and returns only 1 row with the sum.

You can do 2 things, or quit the `SUM` of the SQL or quit the `$db->GetNumRows`.